# WordPress within a WordPress using Windows hosting on GoDaddy

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, godaddy-api

I have a website (www.website.com) which is a WordPress site hosted on GoDaddy with Windows hosting plan.
I have another WordPress website which I want to host as a subdomain ex (Subdomain.website.com). How do I do this?
Is having windows hosting a hindrance in this? |

Comment: You just need to add subdomain on your control panel IF your hosting provider allow you to create new subdomain. Then, you can install your Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Having windows is always a hindrance as well as a security risk and added unnecessarily cost. WordPress runs best on Linux based hosting because it depends on technology that was and is built for Linux including PHP and MySQL. Many plugins have problems. However, you should be able to run WordPress on a sub-domain since it's a different domain as far as WordPress is concerned.